# Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortait')

Tags: android

I imported android project an I got 3 errors

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortait'). AndroidManifest.xml /com.cartmillimaging.fishingmate.MapViewActivity    line 16 Android AAPT Problem
```

same error on different lines.

```
<activity android:name=".MapViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait">
```

For project build target I have selected  Google APIs 2.3.3. 10.
I also enabled Java compiler project specific settings and put compiler compliance error to 1.6.

I am new to android development, so can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you load project I get this error (I use api level 10). I found solution for this. You change screenOrientation to something else, save it, and then return to sensorPortait and everything now is working.

Answer (score 15):

checkout your API level. The following attributes:

`android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` only can work on API level 16+

`android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"` can work under level 15

I think it's a fixed bug

Comment: Hi, when you load project I get this error (I use api level 10). I found solution for this. You change screenOrientation to something else, save it, and then return to  sensorPortait and everything now is working.

Comment: @cashmere> If you found the answer on your own post it as an answer and mark it as accepted to help others having this problem in the future.

Comment: amazing! lost a couple hours in this detail

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo error in the value. The correct name is "sensorPortrait"

Comment: Note that that value is part of a enum (ints) which tells the class which value to use. If the given value is not recognized is just treated as a normal string, which is not accepted for the property screenOrientation

Comment: So, I cannot change in Android manifest, where should I change?

Comment: Yes, of course you can, just fix the property name. It should be like this:

    <activity android:name=".MapViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

Comment: still the same error 
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortrait'). AndroidManifest.xml /com.cartmillimaging.fishingmate.MapViewActivity line 16 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: Impossible ("sensorPortrait" works for me).
Double check that you don't have the same typo in other parts of your manifest. Make sure the data is updated (refresh + clean your project)

Comment: I try to change AndroidManifest.xml, but still with error. When I go to Application tab, I choose MapViewActivity and select sensorPortait without r and now I can run my project.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed what cashmere said.

i changed all

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

to

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

built the project and then changed it back again for all my activites in the manifest and all works good :)

Answer (score 0):

Had this error and couldn't kick it. Some how my build settings had API 13 selected... Selected API 21 and yay no more issue!